# VPN to an android TV box via a MikroTik routerboard

Tags: applications, remote-control, vpn

I have a threefold question:

1. Is it possible to control an android TV box over the internet at a remote location?
2. What program is suggest by the community.
3. And if this is possible how does one set it up?

Keep in mind that this is for a remote site that cannot accept user input and has a MikroTik RB that I will be using to port forward to the devices in question.